# User Registration in ejabberd xmpp server with xmpphp library

Tags: php

I have connected ejabberd xmpp server with xmpphp library. Its working fine. I need to create a user in ejabberd xmpp server using xmpphp library. So i have added following two functions in XMPPHP/XMPP.php file :

https://github.com/delros/XMPPHP/commit/0671b97ae56538fc38fd46d2dba47c3832137e44

and i'm calling the above functions in sendmessage_example.php as follows :

```
<?php

// activate full error reporting
//error_reporting(E_ALL & E_STRICT);

include 'XMPPHP/XMPP.php';


$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('serverhost', 5222, 'admin@localhost', 'password', 'xmpphp', 'localhost', $printlog=false, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);

try {
    $conn->connect();
    $conn->processUntil('session_start');
    $conn->presence();
 $conn->register('uname', 'pass');


    $conn->message('vaiju@localhost', 'This is a test message!');
    $conn->disconnect();
} catch(XMPPHP_Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

I have manually added a user called vaiju. I'm able to connect it and m getting a message in my pidgin client. But user registration is not working.

Please help me...

Here is folder structure of xmpphp library
https://github.com/delros/XMPPHP

Comment: are you sure your connection is successful? because $conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('serverhost', 5222, 'admin@localhost', 'password', 'xmpphp', 'localhost', $printlog=false, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO); in this line you need to add admin only instead of 'admin@localhost'...Please check this..this might cause issue.